# دَوْحَة ؟ — or is و vocalic here?

Tags: arabic

Question may be off-topic, still here it is:

The و in دوحة (like in الدوحة , capital of قَطَر), is it consonantal or vocalic ? (Indicating /aw/ or /u/ ?)

Comment: this sort of question is likely off-topic here. Looking at the transliteration on wiktionary should give you the answer though

Answer (score 0):

As a question about grapheme-to-phoneme relations in Gulf Arabic,و in the name "Doha" is "vocalic", i.e. indicates vowel rather than a consonant. In Classical Arabic, <aw> is somewhat ambiguous because one might claim that it represents a diphthong [au] rather than a vowel+glide sequence, but in this instance, it simply indicates a vowel.

Comment: phonotactically it's unambiguous that the "diphthong" [au] in Classical Arabic has a consonantal /w/ following vocalic /a/